# Expectation of PDF

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with density function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x}{2} &  \text{if}\;  0 \leq x \leq 2& \\ \\
 0 &\text{otherwise}& 
\end{cases}$$

What is $E[|X-E[X]|]$?

I've tried to evaluate E(X). And wouldn't the answer be 0?

But instead the answer given is $\frac{32}{81}$

Comment: Note: the absolute value brackets.  The expected *absolute* displacement from the mean will not be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's evaluate $\mathbb{E}(X)$ step by step. By definition, if $X$ is a continuous RV with PDF $f(x)$ then $\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_\mathbb{R} x f(x) \mathrm{d}x$. In your case since $f(x)=0$ outside of the interval $[0,2]$ we have
$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_0^2 x \cdot \frac{x}2 \mathrm{d}x=\frac12 \int_0^2 x^2 \mathrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac12 \cdot\frac13 x^3 |_0^2=\frac16 (8-0)=\frac86=\frac43\neq 0,$$
which is clearly non-zero. You should carefully check your integration, since this is but basic rules of integration—all that was used is the power rule $\int x^n \mathrm{d}x=\frac1{n+1} x^{n+1}$ and it is really not a matter of probability at this point once you know the definition of $\mathbb{E}(X)$, it's just routine calculus).
Can you now compute $\int |x-4/3| \frac{x}2 \mathrm{d}x$? Note you will have to split it up based of the definition of absolute value and find the appropriate limits of integration.